# Prove that every two sets A,B : $P(A \bigtriangleup B) \not= P(A) \bigtriangleup P(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to show that for every 2 sets this claim are true

$$P(A \bigtriangleup B) \not= P(A) \bigtriangleup P(B)$$
Notes : P is the power set.
can I do that with truth table or it will be too primitive? if not formal way is preferred. 
any suggestions to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the triangle operation on two groups?

Comment: Could you explain the notations?

Comment: @IttayWeiss $$A \bigtriangleup B = (A \cup B )\setminus (A \cap B )= (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$$

Comment: And what's $P(A)$ here?

Comment: @DanielFischer this is the power set.

Comment: In that case $\varnothing \in P(A \bigtriangleup B) \setminus (P(A) \bigtriangleup P(B))$.

Comment: @OfirAttia you are talking about sets then, not groups. In Hebrew set translates to קבוצה while group translates to חבורה. Two quite different things.

Comment: @OfirAttia, if instead of "groups" you had used the much more common and accurate word "set" people, perhaps, would have understood better the question: all your symbols are standard in set theory, a tag which you didn't use, either.

Comment: @IttayWeiss thanks, changed.

Comment: A general remark: It seems you don't really try to solve a problem before you turn to this site to ask if a certain approach you have *might* work. The only way to learn (anything) is to try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, clearly we **always** have

$$\emptyset\in P(A\Delta B)\;,\;\;\text{but also always}\;\;\emptyset\notin P(A)\Delta P(B)$$